# Can GDB debug itself?

Tags: correctness-proof, program-correctness

Can GDB be run on itself? How or why not?
I see something about it http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gdbint_3.html
But GDB might not be written in a language that it can debug?

Comment: Are you looking for a paradox? Note that GDB does not prove correctness.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I mainly wonder how to debug a debugger and I can understand that "self-verifying code" does not seem to exist(?) and (2) what language GDB is written in, if it's C or need to be some other language.

Comment: I was thinking whether a program can "examine" itself.

Comment: On a related note, you might be interested in [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657454/is-gcc-c-compiler-written-in-c-itself)

Comment: How is this a computer *science* question?

Comment: GDB is written in C, and so GDB should be able to debug another instance of GDB running. Sounds strange, really isn't so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's how to do it.

1. Obtain the source code for gdb.
2. Compile with the `-g` flag on.
3. Run `gdb gdb`.